# How to delete an object from array in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to delete an object from array ,when my table view gets `reload`, deleted object from array showing in tableview,I am using `– removeObjectAtIndex:` to delete object from array.
Please help me to delete object from array permanently.Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

      [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      [tableView reloadData];

    }

}
```

Comment: are you reloading your tableview before or after you delete the object from the array?

Comment: `removeObjectAtIndex` should work. Are you sure you are sending it the right index? The first item in the array is index 0 in C, which is different from some languages.

Comment: use [yrArray removeObjectAtIndex:index]; if u already tried what u error are u getting? if possible put code here

Comment: give some code where u remove the object from array.

Comment: Is the problem here that you're not removing the object, or that it's not displaying correctly.  You'll need to either reload the tableview or notify it that you are removing the object in order for it to synchronize with your display.

Comment: Y is this being downvoted? It seems like a perfectly fine question to me. His code would be nice, but the question was only posted 8 mins ago, give him a minute to respond ffs.

Comment: @GeneralMike agree completely.

Comment: @user2169470 can you post all the code of your table delegate functions.

Comment: make sure datasource is from myArray

Comment: Please elaborate on it..

Answer (score 4):

NSMutableArray Methods for Removing Objects:

```
– removeAllObjects
– removeLastObject
– removeObject:
– removeObject:inRange:
– removeObjectAtIndex:
– removeObjectsAtIndexes:
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:inRange:
– removeObjectsFromIndices:numIndices:
– removeObjectsInArray:
– removeObjectsInRange:
```

See:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablearray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And also make sure you reload your table after you delete the object from your array. And send proper count to tableview delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Take one NSMutableArray and then remove object at number of tableview row is selected.Then reload tableview to apply changes.

For example....

```
[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView reloadData];
```

make sure you reload the tableview, and took NSMutableArray not NSArray

Answer (score 0):

I think you deleting the object from temporary array,so it will not remove from main array.so when you reload or viewwillAppear,it is reproducing..